# Updating a single value in a record, within a collection of records Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, insert, record

So I have a custom data type `Person`

```
   data Person = Person{ fname :: String
                        , lname :: String
                        , age :: Int
                        , siblings :: [String]
                        }
```

I have a list of this type, `foo = [Person].`

I'm trying to update a particular `Person`. My process is to match their `fname` (Assuming each name is unique) and then to update their `siblings` values.

```
addSiblingToPerson :: String -> String -> [Person] -> [Person]
addSiblingToPerson siblingParam fnameParam fooParam =
```

I'm really struggling to think 'functionally', if I were to do this in an imperative language I could go through each item in `[Person]` checking to see `if name == fname then this.siblings push newSibling` (Or something along those lines)

I know how to update a record in haskell but I want to return the list of `Person` after updating a single person in the collection of `Person`.

I just can't wrap my head around how to 'think Haskell'

Thank you :(

Comment: Discover the exciting world of [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't think about "updating" something, even though we use that terminology, unless you have a mutable reference and are working in the IO monad.  In this situation the thought process should be "how do I compute a new list that is exactly like the previous one except...".

You could either update a single entry or `map` a modification function across the entire list.  Lets look at the manual, single entry, solution first:

```
addSiblingToPerson :: String -> String -> [Person] -> [Person]
addSiblingToPerson siblingParam fnameParam allPeople = 
    case allPeople of
       []     -> []
       (p:ps) | fname p == fnameParam ->
                     p { siblings = siblingParam : siblings p } : ps
              | otherwise ->
                     p : addSiblingToPerson siblingParam fnameParam ps
```

That is, we traverse the list, keeping any non-matching people and updating the first person with a matching `fname`, being sure to include the rest of the list.

The map solution is functionally different - it will update *all* people who share the given `fname` and it will traverse the whole list.

```
addSiblingToPerson :: String -> String -> [Person] -> [Person]
addSiblingToPerson siblingParam fnameParam allPeople =
      let update p | fname p == fnameParam = p { siblings = siblingParam : siblings p }
                   | otherwise = p
      in map update allPeople
```

Comment: Thank you. "how do I compute a new list that is exactly like the previous one except...". really helped me understand it. Surely it's inefficient to create an entire new list just to modify one value though? (Not saying your answer isn't satisfactory, it's great, really helped me understand) but more so pointed towards Haskell.

Comment: First of all: You are right. Certainly in this situation lists are not the structure you want to use if you desire good performance.  Second: Don't get too hung up on what you believe is efficient too early.  In this example the portion of the list after the first match will be shared - both the pre-update and post-update lists have pointers to a common tail.  In Haskell most values are boxed and what lots of update operations involve is moving pointers to the old structure, old elements, etc.

Comment: Note that this would be inefficient even if you could mutate the list in place. You need to do O(n) work to find the element that needs an update, so doing additional O(n) work to copy non-matching elements is not a terribly big deal.